# Creating a new project: Avoid to use persistence.xml

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a prohect that has enabled auto discovering of entitities, is it possibile, creating a related project to use the same entity and avoid to write classes in the persistence.xml ?

Thank you!

Comment: The JPA API requires a file `persistence.xml`.

Comment: Yes sure, I'm writing about the class element, I mean using the autoscanning also for relating projects.

Comment: The "autoscanning" (`exclude-unlisted-classes`) only applies to JavaEE environments. Some JPA providers support it outside that environment, but you can't rely on it if you want to be portable.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, I just needed to add the jar-file element to my persistence.xml with the relative project